# Groovy Test cases are not running when doing a mvn clean install but the test cases written in Java are getting executed

Tags: java, maven, groovy, maven-surefire-plugin

In my project test cases are written in both java and groovy. When I run the groovy test case individually it is getting executed. However when I run mvn clean install, only the java test cases are getting executed. In pom file the dependency is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4-M1-groovy-4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Compiles Groovy code. -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compileTests</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<!-- Run Spock Tests -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <useFile>false</useFile>
        <includes>
            <include>*.*</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <!-- Run Spock tests with JUnit not TestNG -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please show the full pom file... why using an old surefire-plugin version? Why defining the provider manually (surefire-junit47)? Which JUnit Version (4.X or 5.X) do you use?

Comment: <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

Comment: Quote from the docs: `NOTE: Spock 2.x is based on the JUnit 5 Platform and require Java 8+/groovy-2.5+ (Groovy 3.0 or 4.0 is recommended, especially in projects using Java 12+).` ... so no chance to go via JUnit 4; https://github.com/spockframework/spock

Comment: Added dependency:
```        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope> <!-- Change to test scope -->
        </dependency>
```
Still groovy test cases are not getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly build tests with gmavenplus plugin. If test class files are there in the target directory, try using exactly version 3.0.0-M3 of the surefire plugin. I didn't check 3.0+ versions but this one seems to be the only version from 3.0 family to run Groovy tests. If this is successful you could try also newest versions to find out the one supporting Groovy tests.